# table overflow page

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, multicolumn, width

I created a table with https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables

I tried to limit the column width with 
`|l| p{1cm} |p{2cm} |p{1cm} |p{1cm} |p{2cm} |p{1cm} |p{1cm}|`
But it doesn't see to have any effect.

The generated table

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Compute}                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Pay As  You Go}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Storage}                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Pay As  You Go}                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Trail}                          \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-8} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{Provider}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Terminology}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Unit}                                            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{Other Plans*}}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Terminology}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Unit}                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{Other Plans*}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Period or Value}                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Windows Azure}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}Virtual Server}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}/hr}                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}1}                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}Azure Storage}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}/GB  month} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}1}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}90 day} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

---

After I removed `\multicolumn`, I got errors for
`\multirow{-2}{p{1cm}}{Other Plans*}`

```
 main.tex, line 37
Missing number, treated as zero.

<to be read again> 
                   p
l.37 ...    & \multirow{-2}{p{1 cm}}{Other Plans*}
                                                                    & Termin...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.37 ...    & \multirow{-2}{p{1 cm}}{Other Plans*}
                                                                    & Termin...
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
```

See page 2 of the full example
https://www.overleaf.com/read/ywhjzprxmrgj

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{...}` overrides the `p{1cm}`. If you want to see an effect, drop the `\multicolumn`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of possibilities which don't generate an `overfull \hbox` with a standard `article` documentclass:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\scriptsize\centering
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}
\hline
& Compute & \makecell[l]{Pay As\\ You Go} & & Storage & \makecell[l]{Pay As\\ You Go} &  & Trail \\ 
\cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-8} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{Provider} & Terminology & Unit & \multirow{-2}{*}{\makecell[l]{Other\\ Plans*}} & Terminology & Unit  & \multirow{-2}{*}{\makecell[l]{Other\\ Plans*}} & \makecell[l]{Period\\ or Value} \\ 
\hline
\makecell[l]{Windows\\ Azure} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Virtual\\ Server\end{tabular}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}/hr & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}1 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Azure\\Storage\end{tabular}}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}/GB\\month\end{tabular}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}1 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}90 day \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}\tiny\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
& Compute & \makecell[l]{Pay As\\ You Go} & & Storage & \makecell[l]{Pay As\\ You Go} &  & Trail \\ 
\cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-8} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{Provider} & Terminology & Unit & \multirow{-2}{*}{\makecell[l]{Other\\ Plans*}} & Terminology & Unit  & \multirow{-2}{*}{\makecell[l]{Other\\ Plans*}} & \makecell[l]{Period\\ or Value} \\ 
\hline
\makecell[l]{Windows\\ Azure} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Virtual\\ Server\end{tabular}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}/hr & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}1 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Azure\\Storage\end{tabular}}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}/GB\\month\end{tabular}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}1 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}90 day \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Please note that, for colored cells, I've used an appropriate `tabular` instead of `\makecell`.

I prefer the first, without vertical rules:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- since you not provide any information of your document page layout it is not possible to see how much your table spill-out on right text area border
- limiting table width to width of text is the best make with use of `tabular*`, `tabularx` or one of others similar table environments and for them prescribe desired table width
- with this environments you need to select appropriate column types, for example `p{<width>}` or `X`
- don't use `makecell` with colored table. you can experienced unexpected troubles

see if the following suggestion solve your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace, multirow, tabularx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{L}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{L
        *{2}{>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L L >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L}
                             L}
    \hline
    &   Compute
        &   Pay As You Go
            &   &   Storage
                    &   Pay As You Go
                        &   &   Trail               \\
    \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-8}
\multirow{-2.8}{=}{Provider}
    &   Terminology
        &   Unit
            &   \multirow{-2.8}{=}{Other Plans*}
                &   Terminology
                    &   Unit
                        &   \multirow{-2.8}{=}{Other\\ Plans*}
                            & Period or Value       \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{green!30}
\cellcolor{white}{Windows Azure}
    &   Virtual  Server
        &   /hr
            & 1 &  Azure Storage
                    &   /GB mont
                        & 1 &  90 day               \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

it gives:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

if you have narrower text area, than see, if reducing font size can help you.

Comment: For colored cells, I've used a `tabular` instead of `\makecell`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, i observe this :-). you wrote nice answer (+1) ...

Comment: I got 2 errors after I moved the table to my big document: Illegal unit of measure; Missing number treated as zero. I can't figure out what is causing it, it works fine in the simple illustration.

Comment: @Miranda, without knowing what you doing in your document, i cant say anything. apparently you have in it some error not related to my table code. anyway, you select other answer ...

Comment: Thanks, I have updated Table 5 in https://www.overleaf.com/read/ywhjzprxmrgj, but couldn't replicate the error, I suspect my package is clashing with this solution. I choose the other answer because it doesn't require me to change my existing setting, although I initially thought your solution looks better :(

Comment: @Miranda, you select what you wish. however, you should be fer to people which try to help you. if you not provide all necessary information, we cant help you. and links to some your code is not good idea. after while this link can become death so no one can see, what was your problem. you should modify your question accordingly (with mwe).

Answer (score 0):

I found an option from the original site, to scale table to text width.

I end up doing this:

```
% required packages to your document preamble:
\usepackage{graphicx}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}
% original table
\end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: You should not =use `\resizebox` – it leads to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: But I can't figure out the how to get rid of the errors for `\multirow`