# Table overflows page horizontally

Tags: tables, tabularx

my table is overflowing my page horizontally. I need it to stay within my defined margin for the document and still be displayed completely.

I already tried the following links, but I did not succeed:

• [Latex table goes out of page border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245382/latex-table-goes-out-of-page-border)

• [Horizontal page overflow of tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414179/horizontal-page-overflow-of-tables)

• [table overflow page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455621/table-overflow-page)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Requisitos Funcionais e Não-Funcionais do Sistema}
\label{requisitosfuncionais}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Nome}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Descrição}}                                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prioridade}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Tipo}}  \\ 
\hline
Geração Automática~                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Capacidade de entregar ao usuário \\avaliações geradas de forma automática\end{tabular}           & Essencial                                & Funcional                           \\ 
\hline
Cadastro de Questões                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Capacidade de armazenar questões\\em um banco de dados\end{tabular}                               & Essencial                                & Funcional                           \\ 
\hline
Língua: Português                   & O Sistema deve ser todo em Português                                                                                         & Importante                               & Não-Funcional                       \\ 
\hline
Cadastro de Assuntos                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Capacidade de armazenar assuntos em\\um banco de dados\end{tabular}                               & Essencial                                & Funcional                           \\ 
\hline
Autenticação                        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sistema só poderá ser acessado por\\usuários logados\end{tabular}                                 & Essencial                                & Não-Funcional                       \\ 
\hline
Editor de Texto                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Capacidade de inserir questões estilizadas\\e formatas através de um editor de texto\end{tabular} & Desejável                                & Não-Funcional                       \\ 
\hline
Geração de Gabaritos                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sistema deve entregar ao usuário um~\\gabarito para cada avaliação gerada\end{tabular}            & Importante                               & Funcional                           \\ 
\hline
Acesso Multiplataforma              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sistema deve ser compatível com os\\diversos sistemas e softwares disponíveis\end{tabular}        & Desejável                                & Não-Funcional                       \\ 
\hline
Integridade do Dados                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Dados devem ser armazenados com\\precisão e consistência\end{tabular}                             & Essencial                                & Não-Funcional                       \\ 
\hline
Avaliações Editáveis                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sistema deve permitir que usuário edite\\a avaliação antes de imprimir\end{tabular}               & Desejável                                & Funcional                           \\ 
\hline
Controle de Acesso                  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cada usuário só deverá ter acesso a dados\\pertinentes a ele\end{tabular}                         & Essencial                                & Não-Funcional                       \\ 
\hline
Avaliações diferentes               & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O sistema deverá ser capaz de gerar\\avaliações diferentes a cada vez~\end{tabular}               & Importante                               & Funcional                           \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Werner - I've reopened this posting as it touches on some interesting issues in addition to the main stated objective, viz., to make the tabular material fit inside the width of the textblock.

Comment: @Mico: "Interesting issues"? I still feel it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Werner - The main issue, *viz.*, using a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment (and `X` columns instead of `l` columns), in order to make the tabular material fit inside the textblock is definitely a duplicate. The additional issues -- maybe it's too much to call them "interesting"...-- are (a) using two different widths for the two columns of type `X` and (b) the deliberate non-use of vertical lines and of most horizontal lines. Handling these issues in a deft and sure manner will very much determine the overall visual appeal of the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've set the `tabularx` tab, so I will assume that you're familiar with this package and its main user environment, also called `tabularx`.

Some suggestions:

- Employ a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, and set the overall width to `\textwidth`.
- Don't use the `l` column type, which doesn't allow automatic line breaks, for all four columns. Instead, use `l` only for columns 3 and 4; use a modified form of the `X` column type for columns 1 and 2. That way, LaTeX will automatically find all suitable line-breaks in the first two columns automatically -- no need for those additional `tabular` environments...
- Since the cells in column 2 contain much more material than those in column 1, make the width of column 2 roughly twice that of column 1. (See the code below for how to accomplish this.)
- Don't use vertical lines; they're not needed -- really! Moreover, use only few, but well-spaced, horizontal lines. I suggest you load the `booktabs` package for the macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\addlinespace`. That way, you'll create a table with a much more open and inviting "look". Your readers will be deeply grateful to you.
- While on the subject of making the table look "open" and reader-friendly: Don't over-use **bold-facing**. **Bold-facing** is rarely, if ever, needed in a well-designed table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % modified 'X' col. type
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{Requisitos Funcionais e Não-Funcionais do Sistema}
\label{requisitosfuncionais}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\hsize=0.65\hsize}L >{\hsize=1.35\hsize}L l l @{}} 
   %% Note: 0.65+1.35 = 2 = # of columns of type X
\toprule
Nome & Descrição & Prioridade & Tipo \\ 
\midrule
Geração Automática & 
Capacidade de entregar ao usuário avaliações geradas de forma automática 
& Essencial & Funcional \\ 
\addlinespace
Cadastro de Questões & 
Capacidade de armazenar questões em um banco de dados 
& Essencial & Funcional \\ 
\addlinespace
Língua: Português & 
O Sistema deve ser todo em Português                                                                                         & Importante & Não-Funcional \\ 
\addlinespace
Cadastro de Assuntos & 
Capacidade de armazenar assuntos em um banco de dados                            
& Essencial & Funcional \\ 
\addlinespace
Autenticação & 
Sistema só poderá ser acessado por usuários logados 
& Essencial & Não-Funcional \\ 
\addlinespace
Editor de Texto &
Capacidade de inserir questões estilizadas e formatas através de um editor de texto
& Desejável & Não-Funcional \\ 
\addlinespace
Geração de Gabaritos &
Sistema deve entregar ao usuário um gabarito para cada avaliação gerada
& Importante & Funcional \\ 
\addlinespace
Acesso Multiplataforma &
Sistema deve ser compatível com os diversos sistemas e softwares disponíveis
& Desejável & Não-Funcional \\ 
\addlinespace
Integridade do Dados & 
Dados devem ser armazenados com precisão e consistência
& Essencial & Não-Funcional \\ 
\addlinespace
Avaliações Editáveis &
Sistema deve permitir que usuário edite a avaliação antes de imprimir
& Desejável & Funcional \\ 
\addlinespace
Controle de Acesso &
Cada usuário só deverá ter acesso a dados pertinentes a ele
& Essencial & Não-Funcional \\ 
\addlinespace
Avaliações diferentes &
O sistema deverá ser capaz de gerar avaliações diferentes a cada vez
& Importante & Funcional \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Mico. This works very well.

Comment: @BrunoCamarda - You're most welcome. Just out of idle curiosity: Which document class do you employ, which font and font size do you employ, and how wide is the textblock of your document?